# Scala: why can't I map a function accepting Seq[Char] over a collection of Strings

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I can define a function that accepts a `Seq[Char]`

```
def f(s: Seq[Char]) = s
```

and it works if I pass in a `String`:

```
scala> f("this")
res8: Seq[Char] = this
```

which means that I can use it in a `map`:

```
scala> List("this").map(s => f(s))
res9: List[Seq[Char]] = List(this)
```

So why can't I do this?:

```
scala> List("this").map(f)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Char] => Seq[Char]
 required: java.lang.String => ?
              List("this").map(f)
                               ^
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that because there is no promotion of an implicit conversion `A => B` to `F[A] => F[B]`.  In particular, `f` is actually an instance of type `Seq[Char] => Seq[Char]`, and you would require that the implicit conversion from `String => Seq[Char]` would generate a function `String => Seq[Char]`.  Scala doesn't do two-step implicit conversions such as this.

If you write `s => f(s)`, Scala is free to fiddle with the types so that `s` is converted to `Seq[Char]` before being passed in to `f`.

Comment: I had a feeling it had to do with the two-step implicit conversion limitation.  Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the best way to solve this is:

```
def f[S <% Seq[Char]](s: S): S = /* some code */
```

Then, `map` and friends will work as expected.